# Eclipse : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000ffec (code=1), thread 1557 (Thread-106) error

Tags: android, eclipse, fatal-error

I'm developing an android game, but when i tried to test it in the genymotion, I've got this error "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000ffec (code=1), thread 1557 (Thread-106) error" and don't know how to fix it, can anyone help me please?

I'm using eclipse.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Is usually crashed in your native code. Check the native code and see where cause this crash. Maybe you can print more logs in your native code to check where the code reached.